# how to write this query for this xml data in linq to xml?

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-xml

i've been reading through the linq to xml documentation in msdn and some other tutorials and yet i failed to find the right way to do this query as of now :(

Basically, i want to loop through each student in the class, for each question, keep a counter of individual skill, i.e. for student 123, the tally should be 001.101.033.002.001 - 1, 001.101.035.002.001 - 1, 001.101.033.002.002 - 0. as the skills counter is based on whether the question is right(1) or wrong(0).

```
<assessment name="english101" level="primary 6">
   <class id="23" name="1A">
      <student id="123" name="Jack Black">
         <question id="101" correct="1">
            <skill id="001.101.033.002.001" topicId="033" subtopicId="002" subtopicdesc="Launching a browser" topicdesc="Point and Click">Able to recognize and use desktop icon</skill>

            <skill id="001.101.035.002.001" topicId="035" topicDesc="Typing" subtopicId="002" subtopicDesc="Using Words">Able to write on screen</skill>
         </question>

         <question id="102" correct="0">
            <skill id="001.101.033.002.002" topicId="033" subtopicId="002" subtopicdesc="Launching a browser" topicdesc="Point and Click">Able to recognize and use the mouse</skill>

            <skill id="001.101.035.002.001" topicId="035" topicDesc="Typing" subtopicId="002" subtopicDesc="Using Words">Able to write on screen</skill>
         </question>
      </student>

      <student id="124" name="Tim Robbins">
         <question id="103" correct="1">
            <skill id="001.101.033.002.002" topicId="033" subtopicId="002" subtopicdesc="Launching a browser" topicdesc="Point and Click">Able to recognize and use the mouse</skill>

            <skill id="001.101.035.002.001" topicId="035" topicDesc="Typing" subtopicId="002" subtopicDesc="Using Words">Able to write on screen</skill>
         </question>

         <dtasResult>
            <skill id="001.101.033.002.002" result="weak" />

            <skill id="001.101.033.002.002" result="strong" />
         </dtasResult>
      </student>
   </class>
</assessment>
```

so far the code i have is here:

```
    //Open up the xml and traverse to the student nodes.
                    XElement root = XElement.Load(fileLocation);
                    IEnumerable<XElement> students = root.Elements("class").Elements("student");

                    string currentStudentId = "";
                    foreach (XElement student in students)
                    {
                        currentStudentId = student.Attribute("id").ToString();
                        //this code chunk below doesn't work!
XElement questions = root.Descendants("question")
                                                .Where(question =>
                                                question.Attribute(""));

                        Console.WriteLine(student.DescendantsAndSelf("question"));
                        Console.WriteLine();
                        Console.WriteLine();
                    }
```

i have yet to figure out how to do the looping for each question per student.. and the code in the middle of the foraech doesn't work!!

### Updates:

if i wanted to calculate the total question per student, how would i be able to modify your query above to do so? i try grp.Count(z => z.Correct) and other method but i can't get it right thanks :)

Comment: (note I tweaked the answer a bit more to take "correct" into account etc)

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there more than one way to do this? while going through some linq-to-xml i found there's couple of syntax in querying which is probably what stumped me...

Comment: Oh, dozens ;-p For example, even within the LINQ-to-XML you could use Descendants(), you could use your "let"; etc. Outside of this, you could use your own dictionaries (painful, but very doable); you could run it through an xslt, using Muenchian grouping; you could flatten it first; all sorts of things.

Comment: yea, that's what i thought :( no wonder my headache just keep spinning bigger and bigger. in that case is there a particular good school for me to learn? in terms of ease to learn and not-likely-to-change-from-skin-to-bone in the near future. as i really love linq-to-xml compared to xpath..

Comment: I added a *third* edit, which I *think* does the tally more like you wanted...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Second edit re comment; I think this does what you want...

```
var qry = from cls in doc.Root.Elements("class")
          from student in cls.Elements("student")
          from question in student.Elements("question")
          from skill in question.Elements("skill")
          select new {
            Student = (int)student.Attribute("id"),
            Skill = (string)skill.Attribute("id"),
            Correct = (int)question.Attribute("correct")
          } into denorm
          group denorm by new {
            denorm.Student,
            denorm.Skill
          } into grp
          orderby grp.Key.Student, grp.Key.Skill
          select new {
            grp.Key.Student,
            grp.Key.Skill,
            Tally = grp.Sum(x => x.Correct)
          };

foreach (var row in qry)
{
  Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}\t{2}",
    row.Student, row.Skill, row.Tally);
}
```

Comment: hi Marc i just noticed that the query above ignore the question correct attribute, if should only increment if the correct=1.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure if this is what you want, but I'll give it a try:

```
foreach (XElement student in students)
        {
            currentStudentId = student.Attribute("id").ToString();
            Console.WriteLine(currentStudentId);
            //this code chunk below doesn't work!
            IEnumerable<XElement> correctQuestions = student.Descendants("question").
                                  Where(q => q.Attribute("correct").Value == "1");                
            //Here you would do same for false answers

            //loop through correct answers
            foreach (XElement q in correctQuestions)
            {
                IEnumerable<XElement> skills = q.Descendants("skill");
                foreach (XElement s in skills)
                {
                    //this prints "001.101.035.002.001" etc  
                    Console.WriteLine(s.Attribute("id").Value);
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
```

Comment: hi Lauri, if i'm reading it right with my puny linq-to-xml knowledge, you should just return the skill with the correct=1 right, but when i run it, i get this id="123"
001.101.033.002.001
001.101.035.002.001

id="124"
001.101.033.002.002
001.101.035.002.001, and it's missing the tally for each skill :P